# PHP locate and click object in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, web

i've got iframe in my php document and i want to click on first button, then set values of textbox, click another button, set another textbox value and click last button(they're all in this iframe). Something like this in vb.net:

```
(...).InvokeMember("click")
(...).SetAttribute("value", "user")
(...).InvokeMember("click")
(...).SetAttribute("value", "pass")
(...).InvokeMember("click")
```

And this is code of buttons and textbox1, 2 and 3:

1 button code:

```
<li>
                        <a href="#itemFancy19836" id="19836" class="item fancyboxSee">
                            <img src="https://admin.pukawka.pl/img/itemShop/apple_icon32.png" alt="test1">
                            <span class="before_hover">
                                    <strong>test1</strong>
                                    <small>(ID: 19836)</small> 
                                    <blockquote>test1111</blockquote>
                            </span>
                            <span class="on_hover">
                                <strong>ZOBACZ</strong>
                            </span>
                            <span class="triangle"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

1 textbox code:

2 button code:

```
<a id="fancyboxNext19836" class="fancyboxNext" href="#" onclick="return confirm('Uwaga! Ten item nie wymaga Twojej obecności na serwerze.\nNie będziemy mogli sprawdzić czy Twój nick jest poprawny.\nUpewnij się, że wpisałeś swój poprawny nick, którego używasz na serwerze!')">Dalej</a>
```

2 textbox code:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="8" size="15" name="sms" id="sms">
```

3 button code:

```
<a href="#" class="smsPay fancyboxBtnOk">Aktywuj kod</a>
```

and there is also combobox :D

```
<select id="pay_method19836" class="pay_method" name="pay_method">
<option value="2">SMS</option>
<option value="3">ttt</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know that it is blocked for safety reasons to use elements of the iframe, if the site in the iframe is not on the same server as the parent page